# ConnectionError when using Elastichsearch Python client

Tags: python, elasticsearch, request

I am retrieving some data from elasticsearch docker via below code:

```
def get_results(relation_predictions, entity_predictions):
request_body = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"description": entity_predictions}}
            ],
            "filter": [
                {"term": {"relation.keyword": relation_predictions}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{"local": '9200'}])
try:
    res = es.search(index="main_index",
                    body=request_body,
                    size=1)['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']
    return res
except IndexError:
    d = {'subject': 'missing',
         'description': entity_predictions,
         'relation': relation_predictions}
    return d
```

I am calling above function with below code:

```
 rel_preds_2 = []
    ent_preds_2 = []
    for ent, rel in zip(entity_predictions, relation_predictions):
        rel_preds_2.append(entity_linking.get_results(rel, ent)['relation'])
        ent_preds_2.append(entity_linking.get_results(rel, ent)['subject'])
```

The entity_predictions and relation_predictions are list both have lengths 22000. I am getting below error however during the iterations. I sometimes get below error which interrupts my process

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001CC54065B88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001CC54065B88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted)
```

Do you have any idea why it happens and why it sometimes happens but not always and how I can fix it and make my process reliable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding `time.sleep(0.1)`

```
rel_preds_2 = []
ent_preds_2 = []
for ent, rel in zip(entity_predictions, relation_predictions):
    rel_preds_2.append(entity_linking.get_results(rel, ent)['relation'])
    ent_preds_2.append(entity_linking.get_results(rel, ent)['subject'])
    time.sleep(0.1)
```